# Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS Kernel

Tags: upgrade

I have upgraded my system to Ubuntu 14.04.1, but the Kernel version is still 3.13.0-32-generic. Isn't it 3.13.11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `cat /proc/version_signature` and you'll probably see that it is:

```
Ubuntu 3.13.0-32.57-generic 3.13.11.4
```

You can also use `cat /etc/issue` to check the Ubuntu Version:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to use `uname -r` to know the kernel version, and `lsb_release -a` to know the Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 0):

Current [trusty kernel package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/linux-generic) version is `3.13.0.32.38` which translates to linux version `3.13.0-32` so your fine :-)